# How to number unique values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity

I have some data (without ID) and I want to choose unique values (select identity) and give them an ID (without changing the order). Does anyone know how to do it? MS-SQL.

[image: unique data]

Comment: What DB technology?  Oracle, MS-SQL, MYSQL?  Other

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and a database tag.

Comment: What database?..

Comment: Would giving them a GUID work for you?

Comment: As other have said a table has no order.  Even though it may seem so as it does often repeat but it is not guaranteed.    You can assign ID based on no order but it is not guaranteed the select ... and select .... order by ID will return the same order.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you mean by "not changing the order", given that SQL tables already represent *unordered* sets so they have no ordering. You can assign a number to each unique value in a column using `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by data) as data_id
from t;
```

Comment: Probably coincidence, but it is ordered ascending in the image.

Answer (score 2):

Add an ID column by :

```
alter table ChannelGrName add ID int identity(1,1);
```

which will fill ID column with ordered numbers starting from 1 to the number of existing rows. For future inserts, ID column shall be going on with populating starting from *[number of rows + 1]*.

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fa48d/1)

Comment: I did not know you could add identity to a table with data

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you:

```
create table #temp (rowid int identity, col1 int, col2 varchar(max)...)
insert #temp
select * from your table
```

Comment: When you run the insert, add whatever order by rule you want and that is the order the data will be entered